# Regenerating a winload.exe

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

If one is missing or has a corrupted winload.exe - and winload~1.exe, winloadOLD.exe, etc. do not work - what can you do to regenerate it?  (Such as after a failed logon screen customization.)

Comment: A repair installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sfc /scannow - should do. Eventually offline scan from recovery CD/USB if you cannot boot.

winload.exe is a system protected file and has full access only by "Trusted Installer".
I would not use simple copying, renaming, moving this critical system file !

Copies of winload.exe can be found in:

1. \windows\system32\boot
2. \windows\winsxs subfolders (found in 6 subfolders on my Win 7/64 SP1 system).

The default system loader is "\windows\system32\winload.exe".

Comment: I also found out something interesting in the operation I did a while ago - it looks like copying from another Windows install seems to work.  Can this be confirmed?

Comment: What if `sfc /scannow` cannot repair winload.exe.mui, winresume.exe.mui, winload.exe, winresume.exe, or bootres.dll?  What alternate commands or sfc parameters  can be run?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I renamed

```
C:\windows\system32\winload~1.exe
```

to

```
winload.exe
```

I know, it sounds rediculous, the file has a VERY different size, but at least, I could boot into my installation again and go on form there.

Comment: It looks like that probably wouldn't have worked for the install in my question ("and winload~1.exe, winloadOLD.exe, etc. do not work"), but not sure if I'd actually tried, since it was so long ago.  Thanks!